# How do I get the first row in a record after ordering it? Ruby On Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am working with Ruby on Rails.

I make a query to the model, but I want to get the one register that has the highest value for the average attribute. This is my code:

```
@dish = Dish.where("day = ? and week = ?", params[:day], params[:week])

@dish.order(:average)

@sug = @dish.first
```

**@sug** gets the record with the lowest id, no the one with the highest average.

I have also tried it this way:

```
@sug = @dish.order(:average).limit(1)
```

but it's not working either. How can I get that one register?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to chain the calls like follows.

```
@dish.order(:average).first
```

The call to `.order` does not change the @dish instance, so when you call `@dish.first` the ordering no longer is there.

Comment: It worked! The only change I had to do was to make the call to order(average: :desc) since I am trying to get the highest one. Thanks!

Comment: I think it's clearer to say you have to actually update `@dish`, such as `@dish = @dish.order(:average)` than to say you "have to" chain the calls.

Comment: @meager, I believe in this particular case chaining method calls more clearly and succinctly shows how to accomplish what the TC asked. Since there isn't a bigger picture here I can not presume if there would or would not be value in creating a scope at a higher level. The method you suggest doesn't preserve a higher level scope, but just adds an extra line of code for something already relatively simple; I don't see an added value in this.

Answer (score 1):

`@dish.order` does not order already found dishes, it changes the query to include an order clause.

`@dish = Dish.where("day = ? and week = ?", params[:day], params[:week]).order(:average)` would do what you wanted, and so would

```
@dish = Dish.where("day = ? and week = ?", params[:day], params[:week])
@dish = @dish.order(:average)

@sug = @dish.first
```

Answer (score 0):

The `ActiveRecord::QueryMethods#order` method sorts in [*ascending* order](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods.html#method-i-order) by default, so try explicitly asking for a *descending* order, then taking the first:

```
Dish.order(average: :desc)
    .where("day = ? and week = ?", params[:day], params[:week])
    .first
```

This assumes your `average` attribute is stored in the database, and *not* computed.